# How can i add a .php link in my html file

Tags: php, html

Basically i have a php script that i use to log requests on my website.(ip/browser, etc) which is log.php, how can i include the log.php in my index.html so every time someone visits my website they also get "logged"? I have tried a couple of things and its way off than what i want to do.
Basically i want to include domain.com/log.php on my main page..

I tried so many things so far and nothing has worked, i think its really really simple but i can't make it work.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Sorry for my bad english, not my first language. I hope you can understand what i mean.

Comment: Either use `index.php` instead of `index.html` and then just use `<?php require('./log.php'); ?>`, or send a request to the `log.php` for example using a hidden `<img>` or `<iframe>` or with an AJAX request. Did you try any of those already? In what way did it fail?

Comment: I solved it. I need jquery and then i can attach the php like <script type="text/javascript" src="log.php"></script>

Comment: I don't see why you need jQuery for that. Also, what does log.php output? Probably not a script. This will give you a content type error in the browser.

Comment: Here:https://pastebin.com/7uzhd9UX
Basically it logs the visitor's ip and when they visited

Answer (score 0):

The include statement takes all the text/code/markup that exists in the specified file and copies it into the file that uses the include statement.

Here's an example:

```
<HTML>
<head></head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to this page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>
<?php include ('footer.php'); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "_in my index.html_" Will not work in a `.html` file though, unless the webserver is set up correct

Comment: It does not work :(, a while ago i was able to add it through a href thing but i lost the code :( Literally was a single line

Comment: I think i solved it. I need jquery and then i can attach the php like <script type="text/javascript" src="log.php"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You can really execute a `php` code in a `html` file, what you can do is create a `php` file called `index.php` from there create add your code 'logging' code and then render the content of your page.

example `index.php`

```
<?php

 // your code for logging the request 

  echo <html>...</html>

?>
```